# Jquery add class if a corresponding element hasClass 'active' (trying to streamline my code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Please help - there must be a better way to do this! So basically, in an svg I have a bunch of  elements with class names 1 - 50. And then a bunch of corresponding  elements with id's 1 - 50. 
In a nutshell - if circle 1 has class hotspot-active then path 1 should have class locator-active and so on.

My code works but I really don't want to write 50 if statements! I'm sure this can be done with arrays but my Jquery just isn't good enough. Any help would be massively appreciated.
Here is a small code example from 1 to 3 -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('.1').hasClass('hotspot-active') ) {
$('#1').addClass('locator-active');
}

});

$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('.2').hasClass('hotspot-active') ) {
$('#2').addClass('locator-active');
}

});

$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('.3').hasClass('hotspot-active') ) {
$('#3').addClass('locator-active');
}

});
```

And the HTML will look something like this -

```
<circle class="1" cx="1078.34" cy="656.84" r="12.75"/>
<circle class="2" cx="1547.13" cy="613.3" r="12.75"/>
<circle class="3 hotspot-active" cx="1578.15" cy="221.17" r="12.75"/>

<path id="1" />
<path id="2" />
<path id="3" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [for](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const circlesCount = document.querySelectorAll('circle').length;
    for (let i = 1; i <= circlesCount; i++) {
      if ($('.' + i).hasClass('hotspot-active') ) {
        $('#' + i).addClass('locator-active');
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for taking the time to write this - you've just saved me from a lot of typing !

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the number/id from the "active" circle to then find and "activate" the corresponding path:

```
const hotspot = document.querySelector(".hotspot-active");
const id = Array.from(hotspot.classList).find(Number);

if (id) {               
  document.getElementById(id).classList.add("locator-active");
}
```

But... This only works correctly if the first number found in `.classList` is the id of the corresponding path element

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  randomHotspot();

  const hotspot = document.querySelector(".hotspot-active");
  const id = Array.from(hotspot.classList).find(Number);
  
  if (id) {               
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add("locator-active");
  }
});

function randomHotspot() {
  const possibleHotspots = document.querySelectorAll("div"),
        idx = ~~(Math.random() * 3);
  
  possibleHotspots[idx].classList.add("hotspot-active");
}
```

```css
div.hotspot-active { border: solid 2px red }
p.locator-active { border: solid 2px green }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">1</div>
<div class="2">2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>

<p id="1">Path 1</p>
<p id="2">Path 2</p>
<p id="3">Path 3</p>
```